# Elasticsearch: how to query by exchange rate of years

Tags: elasticsearch

Our company has financial data of over 500k companies over 10 years, including the domestic currency and year-end exchange rates in USD, EUR. Our customers need to find companies in domestic or foreign currencies (USD, EUR), for example, find all companies whose revenue ranges from from to to, with from, to in domestic currency, USD or EUR.

My solution is, store exchange rates into all financial records. Elasticsearch mapping like:

```
{
  "my_index" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "organCode" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "profitsAndLosses" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "revenue" : {
              "type" : "double"
            },
            "usd_rate": {
              "type": "double"
            },
            "eur_rate": {
              "type": "double"
            },
            "yearReport" : {
              "type" : "integer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When customers search, I divided into two cases: domestic currency and foreign currency, with two types of queries as follows: case 1: domestic:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "profitsAndLosses",
      "query": {
        "range": {
          "profitsAndLosses.revenue": {
            "gte": 100000,
            "lte": 200000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

case2: foreign (for example in USD)

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "profitsAndLosses",
      "query": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "lang": "painless",
            "source": "def converted_revenue = doc[profitsAndLosses.revenue].value / doc[profitsAndLosses.usd_rate].value; converted_revenue >= params.from && converted_revenue <= params.to",
            "params": {
              "from": 1000,
              "to": 2000
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But if repeated stored the exchange rates into all records will consume more disk storage, and if there is a need to update the exchange rate for a certain year, I need to re-index millions of records in elasticsearch. I want to store the exchange rates as a reference data, and my query might look like this (pseudo):

```
"source": "def converted_revenue = get_exchangeRate('usd', doc[profitsAndLosses.yearReport].value); converted_revenue >= params.from && converted_revenue <= params.to"
```

Is there any way to create the query like this? Or any solution better?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly encourage you to do the conversions and save the converted rates in each record. It's exactly the right use case for an index. I know storing the result of an operation can feel odd or repetitive, but it'll just be so much easier for you to query and will take less computing resource to calculate if you could use regular [Range](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/query-dsl-range-query.html) queries.

An index trades CPU, RAM and disk for speed, and here you've got a textbook opportunity to trade a bit of disk for simplicity and speed of searching.

500k records * 10 years is 5 million records. A few extra double fields should be relatively little disk space for a dataset of this size. Of course, you know your requirements best, but I'd make very very sure that you can't get the extra disk space before spending time trying to write script queries.

Comment: not just a few extra double fields in my case. We have approximately 120 different financial criteria for search. Each of these criteria if converted_rate is stored, I need to create 240 more fields

Comment: Fair enough. I would indeed look at function scoring in that case. Unfortunately in the time I have I can't come up with a full answer for you. Perhaps post the question to Elastic's community discuss forum, including the detail of 120 criteria?

Comment: I had to accept the old solution I had come up with. I tested and the performance was acceptable